# How do I effectively fight Brutes?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I have only been playing for 3 hours and the brutes are really making it difficult. I get surrounded by 10+ normal gang members and then a brute turns up. I can't ram the brutes in a vehicle and I seem to run out of ammo before being able to do much damage.

Is there a good strategy for fighting them? Is it simply a case of waiting until I have more upgrades?

Playing the game on normal difficulty.

Comment: Not that this is an actual strategy, but during the initial brute encounter, it got itself trapped in the clothing store and couldn't get out. That one was extremely easy to kill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far all I can do is run and gun (emphasis on run). The sniper rifle can do significant damage with headshots, but I rarely have the presence of mind to change to it in the middle of a fight (and it is often disabled in a diversion).

In short, keep upgrading your guns and hit them with your heaviest stuff. You can also try phoning Oleg as he is a physical match for them.

If you can blow up the truck carrying them, you can do significant (sometimes fatal) damage to them if they are still on it when it blows. Next to it doesn't seem to be as damaging. Even if it doesn't kill them, on escort missions they may not run up to you in time if you take out their ride first.

Comment: Oh, also: Tanks. If you are going to start some 4 or 5 ☆ trouble, you should do it in a Tank as the gangs will throw brutes at you every minute or so.

Comment: the upgraded dual-wield pistols are *very* good; I suggest going all the way to level 4 on your pistols and getting dual-wield pretty early. One gets armor piercing bullets, the other (the default Saints gun) gets explosive bullets. Explosives are generally better for Brutes IMHO as they aren't typically armored, just have a ton of health.

Comment: I've upgraded both pistols, but I haven't really played with the default ones much.

Comment: @Cyber Jeff's right, the dual 45's are *amazing*. That's what I've found helps me the most. Plug their head with the entire clip and if you had good aim, that's all you have to do. For the flamethrowing guys, shoot the tanks on their backs first.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Concur, but where the dual 45s upgraded are amazing, dual SMGs fully upgraded to infinite ammo and no-reload-animation are *insane*. Of course, by the time you have those upgrades you should pretty much have finished the game...

Comment: @Shadur At that point in the game I usually hit them with my rifle's ∞ ammo grenade launcher, trying to go for destroying the car in a hit so that I don't have to deal with them (punches are the only thing that can hurt you after purchasing _all_ upgrades; you are bulletproof, fireproof & fallproof but anyone just slapping you can kill you!).

Answer (score 3):

Rocket Launchers and Grenades can help. Picking up a brute's mini-gun helped TONS. I usually use pistols... and you can get them upgraded/dual wield to very heavy damage unloading clips right into a brute's head.

Also you don't HAVE to run up to them and execute them, you can just keep shooting till they die. It was a long time before I figured that out.

Another thing that has been helping is using the Run key + jump when they get close, even if you don't manage to jump out of the way, you are already hitting the key that invokes the 'cut-scene' style evade.

Comment: Upgraded grenade + nearby flammable object = dead brute.

Answer (score 1):

Use the apoca-fist. They seem to kill brutes with three simple punches, but do it quickly before you get attacked.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @user3389 http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Apoca-Fist

Answer (score 0):

Either you shoot the car fast where they are on or you use the fists they kill them pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do which I fined effective is using pistols to headshot them the just using a shotgun in the head hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I use dual .45 shepherd level 4,trow a grenade level 4 to a car nearby him.
Dual D4TH Blossom level 4,hit his dead with 120 bullets,2 satchel charges on him will work to.